# How to use gradient in following code

Tags: android

I have defined XML for gradient.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<gradient 
    android:startColor="#9acd32"
    android:endColor="#ffffff"
    android:angle="180"
    />
```

i want to use gradient in following code.

```
XYRegionFormatter regionFormatter3 = new XYRegionFormatter(Color.BLUE);
```

instead of Color.BLUE

How to use it?

Comment: What is this class XYRegionFormatter ?

Comment: I am ploting a graph in android. 
XYRegionFormatter is class defined in androidplot.xy.XYRegionFormatter

and this i am using in 
LineAndPointFormatter lpFormatter1;

lpFormatter1.addRegion(new RectRegion(0, 4, Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, "R3"), regionFormatter3);

Comment: and where you have use Color.BLUE in that class.

Comment: I have used Color.BLUE in code i have mentioned.

Comment: You can Pass R.drawable.yourxml in res/drawable folder.

Comment: my xml file is already in res/drawable folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:type="radial" android:gradientRadius="250"
        android:startColor="#E9E9E9" android:endColor="#D4D4D4" />
</shape>
```

Comment: this error is coming.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.atos.range/com.atos.range.Range}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/shape.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f020007

But there is entry of shape.xml in R.java

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
XYRegionFormatter regionFormatter3 = new XYRegionFormatter(getResources().getColor(R.color.<xml_file_name>));
```

**Edit:**
 
I realized it needs a Color attribute, while this line tries to cross reference it to a drawable, which is wrong. The gradient actually forms a drawable, while the `XYRegionFormatter` needs a *Color* attribute. Therefore, the gradient drawable cannot be used in this case. There are no other possibilities available in the code to use gradient as color attribute, afaik.
 Also, since the `XYRegionFormatter` does not define any ways to use a *Drawable()*, or even *Paint()* for that matter, it presently does not seem possible to use a gradient for the scenario you are looking at.

Comment: I have defined gradient in drawable resource.
and i tried it. it's not working.

Comment: add a line `android:shape="rectangle"` to your shape attribute.

Comment: this error is coming.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.atos.range/com.atos.range.Range}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/shape.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f020007

But there is entry of shape.xml in R.java

Answer (score 0):

You should do some thing like this .

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient 
android:startColor="#9acd32"
android:endColor="#ffffff"
android:angle="180"
/>
</shape>
```

this xml will be in your res/drawable with name like shape.xml

Now in you code you can pass this like below code.

```
  XYRegionFormatter regionFormatter3 = new XYRegionFormatter(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape));
```

Comment: this error is coming.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.atos.range/com.atos.range.Range}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/shape.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f020007

But there is entry of shape.xml in R.java

Comment: can you just write code where passed Resource is used in `XYRegionFormatter ` this class.

Comment: because your should be use this code for set Resource drawable for  `View.setBackgroundResource();`

Comment: Clear Project and make sure your xml file have no issue .and also check in debug that `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape)` this line return some value not null.